# Clone succeeded, but checkout failed

Tags: github

tried to clone a large project at work. It has worked in the past. But my internet was disconnected and I got this error message :
the question is how can I resume the download without loosing the previously downloaded data

```
$ git clone git@github.com:Unity-Technologies/FPSSample.git
Cloning into 'FPSSample'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 18652, done.
remote: Total 18652 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 18652
Receiving objects: 100% (18652/18652), 213.75 MiB | 214.00 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (9780/9780), done.
Updating files: 100% (12731/12731), done.
Downloading Assets/Textures/Environment/Props/Doors/Doors_Scifi_A/Door_800x500_Floormat_A/Door_800x500_Floormat_A_MaskMap.tif (8.4 MB)
Error downloading object: Assets/Textures/Environment/Props/Doors/Doors_Scifi_A/Door_800x500_Floormat_A/Door_800x500_Floormat_A_MaskMap.tif (4d90adf): Smudge error: Error downloading Assets/Textures/Environment/Props/Doors/Doors_Scifi_A/Door_800x500_Floormat_A/Door_800x500_Floormat_A_MaskMap.tif (4d90adf4e9dd91dd216d6619bbbbe9cf9589898c7f6f705ed079a4043b8111b7): batch request: ssh: Could not resolve hostname github.com: Name or service not known: exit status 255

Errors logged to C:\Users\momen\OneDrive\Bureau\Fps Sample\FPSSample\.git\lfs\logs\20191221T120849.6912638.log
Use `git lfs logs last` to view the log.
error: external filter 'git-lfs filter-process' failed
fatal: Assets/Textures/Environment/Props/Doors/Doors_Scifi_A/Door_800x500_Floormat_A/Door_800x500_Floormat_A_MaskMap.tif: smudge filter lfs failed
warning: Clone succeeded, but checkout failed.
You can inspect what was checked out with 'git status'
and retry with 'git restore --source=HEAD :/'
```

Comment: What are you getting when you execute `git status` command?

Comment: I got  `$ git status                                                                               
fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git`